# first message over socket lost in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, tcp

I have this funny behavior in debug mode which I can't explain to myself.
There are two small client and server applications, and the flow goes like this:

1. Client initiates TCP connection
2. Server accepts and sends message to client requesting packet data size(it's fixed)
3. Client sends the size
4. Server reads the size and initializes some byte array - this works
5. Server blocks on `read()` from the input stream waiting on packets and client sends packets. - this is culprit

It all works when i run the applications, however when I debug the Server - it simply blocks on `read()`. 
If i send more than one message, for example 50, the Server receives 49 of those. Once client closes connection, Server reads -1 from stream and exits, with the first message lost.

The only thing i can think of is that in debug mode, client sends message before server reads it from stream but i don't see how could that be relevant as the message should be there.

Could somebody explain this behavior i am experiencing in debug mode only?

*Note*: client code is there just for debug, so it's not the prettiest.

**Server**

```
private static int sent;

public void processClientInput(HealthCheckSession session) {

    byte[] buffer = session.getBuffer();
    DataInputStream stream = session.getInFromClient();

    int readBytes = 0;
    int totalBytes = 0;
    try {

        while((readBytes = stream.read(buffer)) !=-1) { <---- this blocks in debug on first message

            totalBytes += readBytes;

            if (totalBytes < buffer.length)  {

                continue;
            }

            else {
                totalBytes = 0;
                String packet = new String(buffer, ProtocolValidator.SERIALIZATION_CHARSET);

                sendResponse(packet);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

private void sendResponse(String packet) {
    System.out.println(packet);
    ++sent;
    System.out.println("sent " + sent);
}
```

**Client**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
        IOException, InterruptedException {

    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 10002);

    // get the socket's output stream and open a PrintWriter on it
    PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(
            clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

    // get the socket's input stream and open a BufferedReader on it
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("before read");
    System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine());
    System.out.println("after read");

    byte[] packageData = "100, ABCDZEGHR"
            .getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    String size = String.valueOf(packageData.length);
    outToServer.println(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

        DataOutputStream dis = new DataOutputStream(
                clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("before write");
        dis.write(packageData);
        dis.flush();
        System.out.println("after write");

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

This does not happen in Netbeans debug mode.

Comment: do you by any chance step through it and have an evaluated expression in your watch values which causes the socket read to execute?

Comment: yeah, read blocks. It doesn't return anything, simply blocks. That is if i send only one packet. If i send 50, then 49 are read

Comment: What i am trying to say is, if i send only one packet then it doesn't pass the while condition and just sits there. If i send 50 packets, 49 times body of loop is executed. And this happens only in debug O_O.

Comment: looks like you are going to have to come up with a http://sscce.org/

Comment: Did you solve this? I might have a connected problem. (If I send my first message directly after the connection is established, it is lost. if I first sleep 10ms, it is received)